# SVG range slide bind with div color fill

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm working on an SVG here I want rectangle color fill according to the slider value. when we slide the range slide step 1 then 25% fill and for step 2 50% so on. Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve this output. Any help will be appreciate

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="rm-slider" type="range" min="25" max="100" step="25" value="25" />
<div class="meter-med">
  <svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  Text here....
  </svg>
```

like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important is to set the SVG size with CSS width and to **add** a `viewBox` setting **dimensions**;

You can then size the SVG `<rect>`angles with percentages

The `oninput` Event on the slider updates the width of the *first* SVG `<rect>`:
(or use `addEventListener` if that floats your boat)

```js
  document
    .querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`) // select SVG with same name SVGslider1
    .setAttribute( 'width' , this.value + '%' ) // set percentage width
```

```html
<style>
  svg {
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>

<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" 
 oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('width',this.value+'%')"/>

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 30 6">
  <rect width="25%" height="100%" fill="blue" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

**Notes**

- `stroke-width` is 1 by default, for a thicker line make viewBox **dimensions** smaller

Comment: exactly what I want to achieve I appreciate your effort. Here I want to add some text inside the rectangle can you please suggest me.

Comment: You can do that with SVG ``<text>`` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

Comment: `<g>
          <rect width="25%" height="100%" fill="blue"></rect>
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"></rect>
          <text x="0" y="50"  font-size="35" fill="green">text here</text>
        </g>`     I added like this but text not visible.

Comment: can you please add smooth animation.

Comment: for animation see: [MDN - SVG animation with SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL)

Comment: I got it. It is possible to fill color bottom to top?

Comment: Learn to ``transform="rotate(-90)"`` the rectangle

Comment: When I rotate then the text inside div also rotates.

Comment: What would happen if you only rotate one rect?